# How to use register value as an array-element offset in x86 Assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, offset, cpu-registers

So I have this array:

`fib      BYTE 9, 123, 92, 0, 0, 0, 0`

And I'm wanting to be able to access the different elements of the array and move them, individually, into a register.

I've noticed so far that I can, for example, do this:

`mov al, fib + 2`

to move the 3rd elements value, 92, into the al register.

However, if I try to do this:

```
mov ah, 2
mov al, fib + ah
```

so that I can change the value of ah and thus change the element that I am moving into al, the assembler says that the second line is an "invalid use of a register"

So my question is, is there any way that I can rewrite that second line in a way that would allow me to access the value of the element in the fib array that is offset, from the beginning, by the value that is stored in ah?

---

Edit:

I am writing this code in Visual Studio on Windows 10. The target platform is x86. The entire source code is:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data

    fib     BYTE 9, 123, 92, 0, 0, 0, 0

.code

main PROC

    mov bx, 2
    mov al, [fib + bx]

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

There's really not much to it considering this is just my attempt at learning more about arrays in assembly language

Comment: If you are in 16 bit mode, you can only use a limited subset of addressing modes. Even in other modes, you should use the appropriately sized register. E.g. `mov bx, 2; mov al, [fib+bx]` is legal 16 bit code.

Comment: @Jester When I try out your suggestion, the project builds perfectly fine but then once I run the program, I get an access violation exception thrown at the line ```mov al, [fib + bx]```

Comment: Is this 16-, 32- or 64-bit code (real / protected / long mode?)

Comment: An access violation? I will assume you are running this as a MS Windows application? It doesn't sound like you are running in a 16-bit environment.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm assuming protected mode? It's being ran in debug mode in Visual Studio on Windows 10.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am running this on Windows.

Comment: Yeah the access violation would have also included the number c0000005 . You need to write 32 bit or 64-bit code and that depends on whether your Visual Studio project is x86 or x64. You can't use 16-bit memory operands and expect to address the address space of a Windows application.

Comment: Can you just show us your complete code and tell us if your Visual Studio project is targeting 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) platform. You can tell what platform by looking in the Visual Studio menu bar at the top - there is a drop down box that switches between `x86`/`x64` (but it will display the current target platform). Since your code actually assembled I have to guess the target platform is `x86` (32-bit)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I edited my main post to show the complete code and discovered that the targeted platform is indeed x86.

Comment: In 32 bit mode you want 32 bit addressing, so do `mov ebx, 2; mov al, [fib + ebx]`.

Comment: @Jester That appears to be my mistake. It is working as expected now, after switching to ebx. Thank you!

Comment: Related, sort of a duplicate for the 8-bit register part: [Using 8-bit registers in x86-64 indexed addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39173410).  See comments on the question.

Comment: I may have been a bit hasty in closing this as a duplicate.  I didn't find an ideal duplicate that explains that register size implies address-size (other than as a small part of my larger answer), so you should use pointer-width registers in addressing modes.  If anyone wants to answer this, we can reopen.