# Was there ever 8-bit memory addressing in the original 16-bit x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, addressing-mode

In real mode and 32-bit protected mode, 16-bit addressing is used to reference memory via the ModR/M byte. This addressing is only supported in i386 instructions with use of legacy prefixes, and entirely unsupported in x86-64 instructions.

However, the ModR/M byte is also used by the 8-bit specific opcodes, which makes me question if 8-bit addressing was present in the **original** 16-bit x86 instruction set. Although an 8-bit address is very limited, it'd be entirely possible to encode such an instruction in the same style as 16-bit instructions with a different opcode.

For example, instead of

```
add (bx, si), ax
```

you'd have

```
add (bl, dh), al
```

It's hard to find any pre-i386 documentation, so I'm in the dark. Was this ever supported?

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe so. Nobody ever said "256 bytes ought to be enough for anybody" ;)

Comment: No, addressing is a16, a32, or a64. There is no a8 addressing size. The only similar thing is `xlatb` which loads from `byte [ds:rbx/ebx/bx+al]`.

Comment: the 8088/86 docs were pretty easy to find pdfs of the original iapx88 book.  I got the pdf and can buy originals on amazon as well for like eight bucks.  Hmm that 8 bucks is from intel sold through amazon, used sellers from five bucks...if you get the right pdf, even though it is a scan, you can do text searches...

Comment: 20 bit address, not counting the i/o vs mem signal.  segment/offset, offset by 4 bits.   this was before intel started splitting them into two books one for hardware one for software.

Comment: http://bitsavers.org is a good source for historic documentation.  [Here](http://bitsavers.org/components/intel/8086/9800722-03_The_8086_Family_Users_Manual_Oct79.pdf) for instance is the 8086 User's Manual.  You may also be interested in the [Retrocomputing.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only via [XLAT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xlat:xlatb), which effectively does `mov al, [bx + al]` (which is *not* encodeable as a `mov`).

Modern 16-bit real mode uses the same machine-code format as 8086, that's what it means to be backwards compatible.  (With only very minor differences, like that there's now an instruction-length limit of 15 bytes, vs. 8086 would happily fetch an unlimited number of prefixes, even if that meant wrapping around IP within a 64k segment full of `rep` prefixes.)

[NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes) lists all the ModRM modes: they only include 16-bit registers.

`add [bx + si], al` is encodeable (as `00 00`), but `add [bl + dh], al` isn't.

PDFs of 8086 manuals are available if you want to check historical documents.  Also, Stephen Morse, the primary architect of 8086's ISA, wrote a book "The 8086/8088 primer", which is now available for free on his web site: https://stevemorse.org/8086/.

Earlier ancestors of 8086, like 8080 which only has 8-bit registers, [are *not* x86 CPUs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/the-start-of-x86-intel-8080-vs-intel-8086).

---

Related:

- [Using 8-bit registers in x86-64 indexed addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173410/using-8-bit-registers-in-x86-64-indexed-addressing-modes) - nope, the 32/64-bit mode version of `ModRM [+ SIB]` address encoding can't do that either.
- [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) (32 and 64-bit)
- [Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: [bx] works, [cx] doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866854/differences-between-general-purpose-registers-in-8086-bx-works-cx-doesnt)