# Why am I getting a "Must be Same Size" and "Invalid Use of Registers" when I'm passing a BYTE ptr to a PROC?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm asked to pass a pointer to an array of byte and make some checks in a PROC and return. I read on Stackoverflow that first I need to dereference the ptr then access it. I'm doing that on line 36 and 37  but this approach is giving me:

```
A2022 instruction operands must be same size
A2032 invalid use of register
```

when I try to assembly this code. both arr, pointer and the register is same size (8-bits) and I don't understand why am I getting this error. First error, instruction operands must be same size is for line 36 which is `mov bh, arr` and the second error invalid use of register is thrown for line 37 which is `mov dl, [bh+ecx-1]`.

Here's the code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    minArr BYTE 5,2,4,1,3
    maxArr BYTE 9,5,8,4,6
    pinArr BYTE 6,3,4,3,4
    pinArr2 BYTE 5,4,6,2,5
    pinArr3 BYTE 6,2,6,2,5
    pinArr4 BYTE 7,3,7,3,2
    val1 BYTE ?
    val2 BYTE ?
    num  BYTE ?
    str1 BYTE "Valid",0
    str2 BYTE "Invalid",0

.code
Validate_PIN PROC, arr:ptr BYTE
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov edx, 0
mov ecx, 5

    L1:
    mov al, [minArr+ecx-1]
    mov bl, [maxArr+ecx-1]
    mov bh, arr
    mov dl, [bh+ecx-1]
    mov num, dl
    
    .IF(num < al) || (num > bl)
    mov edx, OFFSET str2
    mov eax, 0
    mov eax, ecx
    ret
    .ENDIF

    loop L1

    mov edx, OFFSET str1
    mov eax, 0

ret
Validate_PIN ENDP


main PROC
    invoke Validate_PIN, addr pinArr
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt

    invoke Validate_PIN, addr pinArr2
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt

    invoke Validate_PIN, addr pinArr3
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt

    invoke Validate_PIN, addr pinArr4
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt


main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Which lines are 36 and 37, and which lines does MASM complain about?

Comment: Sorry for that, it's for the ```mov bh, arr``` and ```mov dl, [bh+ecx-1]``` lines just below L1

Comment: Edited the question to better reflect where the error is being thrown

Comment: There is no addressing mode `[bh+ecx-1]`. Also, `arr` is an address you definitely don't want to load it into `bh`. Use `ebx` in both places.

Comment: I just tried that and it gave me ```byte register cannot be first operand``` error.

Comment: EBX isn't not a byte register (it's a dword, 4 bytes), so an error message complaining about a byte register makes no sense if you tried what Jester suggested.  See also  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) and [Using 8-bit registers in x86-64 indexed addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39173410) (you can't)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help. I was able to find what was the reason and fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Jester and @Peter Cordes (thank you!), I made the following change in the PROC code block which fixed both issues and the program works without any issue.

```
L1:
     mov al, [minArr+ecx-1]
     mov esi, arr
     mov dl, [esi+ecx-1]
     mov num, dl
     mov bl, [maxArr+ecx-1]
```

Comment: `mov ebx, 0` / `mov bl, [maxArr+ecx-1]` would be more efficiently written as `movzx ebx, byte ptr [maxArr+ecx-1]`.  Also pick a different register for the pointer, like ESI or EDI, so you don't have to keep reloading EBX inside the loop.

Comment: Updated the code which utilizes the ESI register and removed reloading EBX. Thanks Peter.